# Calculating the surface area with parabolic coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the surface area of 
>   $x^2 + y^2 -18z=81$ with the surface $-4.5<z<0$
>   using this variable change:
>   $$x=uv\cos\phi\\y=uv\sin\phi\\z={1\over2}(u^2-v^2)\\u,v\ge0,\ 2\pi\ge\phi\ge0$$

I'm having trouble determining the integrals limits.

Comment: with "$z=0$", so the result is not a surface

Comment: I meant till z=0. as 4.5<z<0

Comment: could you edit it, one more thing the transformation should be $x=u\cos\phi$ not $uv$

Comment: no... this is the transform given in the question.